# error: variable has incomplete type 'void'

Tags: python, c++, gcc

I am compiling a c++ code on my Mac machine. I use the terminal to run the setup file using python. When I compile the code to make the .so file, I receive the following errors:

```
python setup.py build
running build
running build_ext
building 'cec13_func' extension
gcc -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -dynamic -arch x86_64 -DNDEBUG -g -O3 -arch x86_64 -I/Applications/Canopy.app/appdata/canopy-1.5.4.3105.macosx-x86_64/Canopy.app/Contents/include/python2.7 -c cec13_func.cpp -o build/temp.macosx-10.6-x86_64-2.7/cec13_func.o
cec13_func.cpp:91:6: error: variable has incomplete type 'void'
void test_func(x, f, nx, mx, func_num);<br>
     ^
cec13_func.cpp:92:1: error: expected unqualified-id
{
^
2 errors generated.
error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

and here is the code:

```
double x[6]={1,2,3,4,5,6};
double f[2]={0,0};
int nx = 2;
int mx = 3;
int func_num = 1;

void test_func(x, f, nx, mx, func_num)
{
    int cf_num=10,i;
    if (ini_flag==1)
    {
        if ((n_flag!=nx)||(func_flag!=func_num))
        {
            ini_flag=0;
        }
    }

    if (ini_flag==0)
    {
        FILE *fpt;
        char FileName[30];
        free(M);
        free(OShift);
        free(y);
        free(z);
        free(x_bound);
        y=(double *)malloc(sizeof(double)  *  nx);
        z=(double *)malloc(sizeof(double)  *  nx);
        x_bound=(double *)malloc(sizeof(double)  *  nx);
        for (i=0; i<nx; i++)
            x_bound[i]=100.0;

        sprintf(FileName, "input_data/M_D%d.txt", nx);
        fpt = fopen(FileName,"r");
        if (fpt==NULL)
        {
            printf("\n Error: Cannot open input file for reading \n");
        }

        M=(double*)malloc(cf_num*nx*nx*sizeof(double));
        if (M==NULL)
            printf("\nError: there is insufficient memory available!\n");
        for (i=0; i<cf_num*nx*nx; i++)
        {
                fscanf(fpt,"%Lf",&M[i]);
        }
        fclose(fpt);


        fpt=fopen("input_data/shift_data.txt","r");
        if (fpt==NULL)
        {
            printf("\n Error: Cannot open input file for reading \n");
        }
        OShift=(double *)malloc(nx*cf_num*sizeof(double));
        if (OShift==NULL)
            printf("\nError: there is insufficient memory available!\n");
        for(i=0;i<cf_num*nx;i++)
        {
                fscanf(fpt,"%Lf",&OShift[i]);
        }
        fclose(fpt);

        n_flag=nx;
        func_flag=func_num;
        ini_flag=1;
        //printf("Function has been initialized!\n");
    }


    for (i = 0; i < mx; i++)
    {
        switch(func_num)
        {
        case 1: 
            sphere_func(&x[i*nx],&f[i],nx,OShift,M,0);
            f[i]+=-1400.0;
            break;
        case 2: 
            ellips_func(&x[i*nx],&f[i],nx,OShift,M,1);
            f[i]+=-1300.0;
            break;
        default:
            printf("\nError: There are only 28 test functions in this test suite!\n");
            f[i] = 0.0;
            break;
        }   
    }
}
```

I need some advise on it.
Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [About] page soon.  More urgently, please read up on how to create an MCVE ([How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)).  The problem you're reporting is not in the code shown; the error message refers to line 91 and you've not got 91 lines of code. Therefore, we have no idea what's missing that is causing the trouble, and we can't help you.Please create a minimal example (30 lines should be plenty), and show us the compiler messages from compiling exactly the code you post in the revised question.

Comment: Declare your parameter types.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This...

```
void test_func(x, f, nx, mx, func_num)
```

...is totally broken: function arguments need to specify *both* a data type (e.g. `int`, `double`, `const char*`) and an identifier.  The later usage of these identifiers implies they're variable names and not `struct`/`class`/`union`/`enum` or `typedef` names), so it's the *types* that are missing.

Further confusing things, atop the file there's:

```
double x[6]={1,2,3,4,5,6};
double f[2]={0,0};
int nx = 2;
int mx = 3;
int func_num = 1;
```

These have the same names as the `test_func` function arguments.  Perhaps you want to put them inside the function calling `test_func`, then pass them during the call?  Alternatively - simpler but less flexible - if `test_func` only needs to be run with those specific arguments, you could put them at the start of the `test_func` body, and leave the argument list empty (i.e. `test_func()`).

Finally, your file extension is `.cpp` - implying C++, but your compile line is using `gcc` which is for C.  The code itself looks like it only uses the C subset of C++, not that that means you can't compile it with `g++`.